# Scanning With sort_key in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table that will contain < 1300 entries at about 600 bytes each. The goal is to display pages of results ordered by epoch date. Right now, for any given search I request the full list of ids using a filtered scan, then handle paging on the UI side. For each page, I pass a chunk of ids to retrieve the full entry (also currently a filtered scan). Ideally, the list of ids would return sorted, but if I understand the docs correctly, only results that have the same partition key are sorted. My current partition key is a uuid, so all entries are unique.

**Current Table Configuration**
[image: Table general information]

Do I essentially need to use a throwaway key for the partition just to get results returned by date? Maybe the size of my table makes this unreasonable to begin with? Is there a better way to handle this? I have another field, "is_active" that's currently a boolean and could be used for the partition key if I converted it to numeric, but that might complicate my update method. 95% of the time, every entry in the db will be "active", so this doesn't seem efficient.

**Scan Index**

```js
let params = {
    TableName: this.TABLE_NAME,
    IndexName: this.INDEX_NAME,
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    ProjectionExpression: "id",
    FilterExpression: filterSqlStatement,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: filterValues,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#n": "name"
    }
};
let results = await this.DDB_CLIENT.scan(params).promise();
let finalizedResults = results ? results.Items : [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your dataset is relatively small you might try a fixed partition key with a sort key of the date and the UUID. You'd query by the partition key (which would be a fixed value) and the results would come back sorted. This isn't the best idea with large data sets, but < 1300 is not large.

Comment: I was thinking my other option would be to restore my previous schema without a sort key (so I could continue to use just the id for query and batchGet) and then sort the returned ids on the API side before returning them to the client. My understanding is that since I'm performing a scan, it doesn't matter if I return just the id or the id and the create_date, since I've already iterated all the entries.

Comment: If you need to be able to do a get then I'd suggest a different approach. Use just a partition key with your UUID on the table. Add a GSI with the data that I suggested. Query the GSI. There is no reason for you to get all the data at once. Even if you want to filter, you can filter in DynamoDB and still get the data back sorted.

Comment: To confirm... you are suggesting that the base table have a primary key of uuid and no sort key. Then add a GSI with is_active (or a similar fixed value) as the primary key and create_date as the sort key. For my initial filtered scan where I return ids for entries matching the filter, query the GSI instead of the base table. If I want to filter against other fields, do I need to include non-key attributes within the GSI, or how does Dynamo know?

Comment: That's correct. You will want to include non-key attributes in the GSI to filter on them. Your data is small, so I'd project everything into the GSI.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight! I've read a lot of the documentation and other Q&A, but understanding the differences and applications of sort key, GSI and LSI doesn't seem trivial when you come from a relational SQL background. :)

Comment: One more question... it seems like regardless of the ScanIndexForward value, I am getting the results in ascending numeric order, but I want to see the most recent entries first. Is there something else I need to do to reverse the order?